# How to include a Runtime file for @include in JSP

Tags: jsp

To include another file in JSP, we use the @include tag

*<%@ include file="NameOfFile"%>*

In my case i want to include a html file whose name will known during the run-time - i,e from Database.

How can I do this in JSP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply using jsp:include :

```
<jsp:include page="<%= htmlFileName %>" />
```

It works in my project where the file is stored in session to reload correctly the part updated with ajax

Comment: Thank you!  I was struggling with the syntax and surfing for answers and yours was right to the point and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Include Directives**

```
<%@include file="<%=FileName%>"%>
```

or **JSP Include Action**

```
<jsp:include page="<%=FileName%>"/>
```

the different is include directive includes a file during the translation phase.

while JSP Include Action includes a file at the time the page is requested

I recommend Spring MVC Framework as your controller to manipulate things.
use url pattern instead of parameter.

example:

```
www.yourwebsite.com/products
```

instead of

```
www.yourwebsite.com/?p=products
```

Watch this video [Spring MVC Framework](http://youtu.be/Q6hZQ5SzGyM)