# how can i call one jsp page to another jsp page

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

Hi I have one Jsp page and i want to call that jsp page in my another jsp page. for example i have includefile.jsp page

```
 <html>
<body>
    <b><font color='red'> Hello World</font></b><br>
    <b><font color='red'> HTML file is included in JSP page<font></b>
</body>
</html>
```

and i have include.jsp page where i want to call the first jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<%@ include file='includedFile.jsp' %>
</body>
</html>
```

but this code is not working. I will really appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file and also make sure about the directory structure that Are you giving the right path of `includedFile.jsp`

Comment: yes i am giving the right path. both jsp are in the same folder and i dnt knw whats wrong with it and i have seen that example of stack over flow also but i am unable to make my code work with that example.

Comment: try to remove <html> and <body> tags from your includedFile.jsp and then check

Comment: o I jsut see! at the start of question you wrote file name `includefile.jsp` and in the code , you used `includedFile.jsp`.Make sure that you are giving right name as well as case sensitivity in file name

Comment: yeah the name I have corrected and even i have tried removing <html> and <body> tag still it is not working

Answer (score 2):

In your include.jsp page

```
<html>
<body>
<form action = "includeFile.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="open other jsp">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**make sure to place both JSP files in same folder.