# How to include the repeated content in every webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I'am making a dynamic website in which the positioning and components of certain components like the fixed header, menubar, footer etc are common in almost all the pages. So how do I include this fixed components in my every webpage? I'am using JSP and javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnajb/index.html:

> **Reusing Content in JSP Pages**
>
> There are many mechanisms for reusing JSP content in a JSP page. Three
>   mechanisms that can be categorized as direct reuse are discussed here:
>
> 1. The include directive
> 2. Preludes and codas
> 3. The jsp:include element
>
> An indirect method of content reuse occurs when a tag file is used to
>   define a custom tag that is used by many web applications.
>
> The include directive is processed when the JSP page is translated
>   into a servlet class. The effect of the directive is to insert the
>   text contained in another file (either static content or another JSP
>   page) into the including JSP page. You would probably use the include
>   directive to include banner content, copyright information, or any
>   chunk of content that you might want to reuse in another page. The
>   syntax for the include directive is as follows:
>
> ```
> <%@ include file="filename" %>
> ```
>
> For example, all the Duke’s Bookstore application pages could include
>   the file banner.jspf, which contains the banner content, by using the
>   following directive:
>
> ```
> <%@ include file="banner.jspf" %>
> ```
>
> Another way to do a static include is to use the prelude and coda
>   mechanisms described in Defining Implicit Includes. This is the
>   approach used by the Duke’s Bookstore application.
>
> Because you must put an include directive in each file that reuses the
>   resource referenced by the directive, this approach has its
>   limitations. Preludes and codas can be applied only to the beginnings
>   and ends of pages. For a more flexible approach to building pages out
>   of content chunks, see A Template Tag Library.
>
> The jsp:include element is processed when a JSP page is executed. The
>   include action allows you to include either a static or a dynamic
>   resource in a JSP file. The results of including static and dynamic
>   resources are quite different. If the resource is static, its content
>   is inserted into the calling JSP file. If the resource is dynamic, the
>   request is sent to the included resource, the included page is
>   executed, and then the result is included in the response from the
>   calling JSP page. The syntax for the jsp:include element is:
>
> ```
> <jsp:include page="includedPage" />
> ```
>
> The hello1 application discussed in Packaging Web Modules uses the
>   following statement to include the page that generates the response:
>
> ```
> <jsp:include page="response.jsp"/>
> ```

So you may use

```
<jsp:include page="includepage.jsp" />
```

Comment: Copied without attribution from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro8.html

Comment: @Pekka웃: yes thats it..!! thankyou..!! i will add it

Comment: As said, it is not acceptable to just copy sources verbatim, even if you link to them. You are expected to come up with an answer on your own.

Comment: hey my edit limit is over..can you  please edit my post with the link..!!

Comment: I edited it in, but the post may still end up getting deleted altogether by a moderator because the quote is the only thing in the post. In the future, really don't do that any more.

Comment: Wait for a moderator to sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are including static content then you can use

```
<%@include file="includes/header.html" %>
```

or for dynamic content

```
<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
<head>
<?php include("path/webpage.html"); ?>
</head>
```