# Multiple Params in JSP Include

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

This line:

`/${initParam['webinf']}${initParam['test']}header.jsp`

Prints out:

`/WEB-INF/test/header.jsp` and if I copy this into:

`<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/test/header.jsp" %>` it works perfectly.

However, if I use the first line of code directly in the statement like this:

`<%@ include file="/${initParam['webinf']}${initParam['test']}header.jsp" %>`

I get the error:

`Sun Feb 16 15:03:56 GMT 2014: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/test/index.jsp (line: 10, column: 9) File "/${initParam['webinf']}${initParam['test']}header.jsp" not found`

Comment: Include directives don't parse EL. A dynamic include might, or you could use something more like actual templating. Static includes happen at compile time, the values aren't known, and it doesn't do late evaluation.

Comment: Use a dynamic include? What's the point of using a context paran, though? Easier to change the JSP, and no restart is required.

Comment: <jsp:include page="..." />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
  <jsp:include page="..." />
```

This will evaluate JSP EL in `"..."`.

Some more info here [Include another JSP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file)