# Best practices for separating concerns in HTML projects

Tags: javascript, html, oop, spring-mvc

I'm an experienced Java developer just beginning to learn HTML.

I'm working on a project that uses Spring MVC as a back-end framework. On the front-end, my index page has several rather complex elements, each involving 150+ lines of html. As an OO-programmer at heart, I hate how long my index.html is, and my OO instincts are compelling me to split some/all of these elements off into their own html files, particularly given that there is a possibility that some of them can be reused on other pages. I've come across examples of HTML tags being embedded into one another, but I haven't found much discussion about whether or not doing so is in line with best practices.

What *are* the best practices when it comes to modularization code reuse and the separation of concerns in modern HTML web-applications?

Comment: Are you using (or expected to use) a specific [Java web framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java)?

Comment: @RichardEverett - yes, I'm using Spring MVC on the backend (Spring-data-Neo4j to be precise). I'm interested to hear how that might affect your answer.

Comment: you should specify that in your question, as there are tons of possible solutions

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Thanks, updated. I'm very curious about what Spring makes possible with regard to my question: I'm relatively new to it as well, and so far have focused mainly on the model and controller aspects of it. What it capacitates with respect to the View is a newer area of thought for me, and I suspect that understanding how it affects this particular question will help me grok that.

Comment: I'm not using SpringMVC, but in a java project I work on we use [Sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home) and [jsp:include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file). Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I feel like some php would help out tons for you, and then you could just do a `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` to build everything

Comment: Assuming that the OP wants to learn php, which he has not indicated.

Comment: I unfortunately don't know any Java so I can't exactly help with that, I am just saying from personal experience what I have done to do basically exactly the same thing

Comment: @RichardEverett The OP doesn't have to learn PHP to figure out the include tag. This is an extremely simple process and as a Java developer I'm sure it wouldn't take more than 1 minute of research to understand.