# Call several method from jsp + Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

i'm new to jsp + spring and i have this problem:
i have two @RequestMapping that respond to "onWork" and "onPending". Both return a list of activities and i would like to call them in the same page, for example:

```
<div id="onWork">
    here i want to display onWork
</div>
<div id="onPending">
    here i want to display onPending
</div>
```

I really like to modularize them and create two page: one that display onWork and another that display onPenging, so i could reuse that "fragment" every time i want, without duplicate the code.

How can i do that using jsp, jsp:invoke, jsp:fragment etc ?

Thanks

Comment: The word you are looking for is include:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `<c:import>` from the JSTL to import a common fragment, or `<jsp:include>`, which allows you to pass variables into the fragment, which you'll probably need to do from the fragment's parent, in each of the divs you're shown above (see `<jsp:param>`).

Comment: Yes thanks i've tested it and it works. c:import have a context parameter, what is this ?

Comment: Cool. The StackOverflow convention is that you mark this answer as correct, by ticking it, and then vote up the answer by clicking the grey up arrow above the 0.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include more details of the context parameters and to make that part of my answer clearer.