# Can i use include directive in anchor tag?

Tags: java, html, mysql, ajax, jsp

i want include content of another jsp into my current jsp

```
 <a href="<jsp:include page="ans1.jsp">
            <jsp:param name="q" value="<%=i+1%>"/>
                  <jsp:param name="n<%=i%>" value="<%=rs2.getInt(1)%>"/>
        </jsp:include>">50-50</a>
```

Is it correct way

Comment: Check this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file. You don't need to use the 'href '

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this.**

```
 <%@include file="filename.jsp" %>
```