# Java code statement inside jsp not executing when including in other jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a folder in my project and some jsp file into that folder and I want to check valid session on each page. So I have created a JSP file that contains the session checking code, inside web-inf folder and including that file into other jsp file but the code is executing but response.sendRedirect() not working.

So I have Admin folder that contain all files, WEB-INF/jsp/SessionValidate.jsp file(this file has to be included into admin folder's file. See the comments in the code

Admin/xyz.jsp

```
        <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/SessionValidate.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

WEB-INF/jsp/SessionValidate.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%
    if(session.getAttribute("Roles")==null){
        response.sendRedirect("/Shopping/Login");
        <!-- response.sendRedirect(..) -->
        System.out.println("hello2");
        <!-- Hello is printing -->
    }
    else{
            if(!session.getAttribute("Roles").equals("ADM")){
                response.sendRedirect("/Shopping/User");
            }
            else{%>
                <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/admin.jsp"></jsp:include>
            <%}
        }%>
```

So when I paste this code directly into the xyz.jsp its working but not like this.

Comment: actually is possible debug jsp with java code inside, if you put a debug point in the page when inclued does it stop there? if you put some html code like a simple write in the inlcued jsp does it show?

Comment: Yes the code is executing Hello is printing which means the if condition is triggering but not redirect

Comment: The question is answered here : [Include another JSP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file#9110412)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing a dynamic include with

```
 <jsp:include page="....
```

try this syntax

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/SessionValidate.jsp" %>
```

Comment: Thanks its working now. RIght Syntax is  <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/SessionValidate.jsp" %>