# How to pass a map into jsp substructure?

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, tags, include

I have several similar structures on the page. Each of the structure consists of a header and several checkboxes. In the java code I am creating a map  for each set of data and pass them into the service.

On the main jsp page I get the service and can read these maps keys and values. But this way I will repeat the same code many times. So, I have to create something that looks like a function with a parameter, and that something will insert pieces of html code into the main page.

I can call included jsp file with a simple string parameter as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file).

```
        <jsp:include page="groop_checkbox_with_header.jspf">
            <jsp:param name="mapName" value="investQuestionsExperience"/>
        </jsp:include>
        ....
        "${param.mapName}" - for use in the included jsp file
```

But I cannot set a parameter to a map. I could set a parameter to a map name and to get the map from the service/request/session using the map name inside the included jsp. But how to get the service/request/session in the called jsp file? It seems, I have to send a parameter with some non-trivial content.

***But how?***

I could use jsp `tag` instead of `include`. But the problems remains practically the same.

Please, notice, that I am using pure JSP without JSTL `<c: >` tags and I cannot use the last ones.

Comment: Create a custom tag.

Comment: Using a tag, I again can pass only simple string parameters. And I need to pass a map. Or a name of the map, but then I have to pass service/request/session somehow. How can I get it there?

Comment: You cannot pass a Map using a *Parameter* however you can create a Map in java code and set this as a  request *Attribute* for use in the JSP. http://learnjava4enterprise.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/difference-between-attribute-and.html

Comment: I think, your help to my another question will bring me to the working result faster, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, into your included JSP, the `request` object *is the same* than the calling JSP's. You can always access it through `pageContext.getRequest()`.

Same about the session (can access it through `PageContext.getSession()` or super-variable `session`), but I suggest you to use the request for this matter.