# how to show another jsp in another jsp div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i Call another jsp in a div.
Actually execpt my Div all remaing data remains same. so I have Give diffrent return diffrent jsp (for diffrent UI) in that div in diffrent conditions. 
and the child jsp have some fill data which i need to get from server.

Mens firslty main.jsp should load then child.jsp load in side dive with get data from server

```
main.jsp
........
.......
<div>
  // here i want to show another jsp  after data get from sever  child.jsp
</div>
.......
.........
```

Comment: Use `<%@ include file = "other_file.jsp" %>`

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file

Answer (score 0):

```
main.jsp
........
.......
<div>
<jsp:include page="<%=NAME%>" /> 
</div>
.......
.........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jsp:include scriptlet

```
  <jsp:include page="file.jsp" />
```

Or can include a file using following syntax

```
 <%@ include file="filename" %>
```

Here is the link to the tutorial that could be helpful

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html